# How to get repository current state?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

For some time I was not involved in the project.

I click update. and I saw progress. I tryed to update one more time but I don't see progress. Thus I made resolution that now I have last revision locally.

But if I click commit I see resources for commit. Looks like I have more code than repository. Maybe some sources were moved or I don't know.

I know that I can remove folder entirely and make checkout newly but I want to find out more elegant decision.

I use tortoise svn.

My goal - get identically state locally and in repository.

Comment: why don't you do a new `svn checkout`? check the repo's log at least.

Comment: because it is excessively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved what I want by following steps

1. revert
2. update